# Issue with multi tabs with user preference

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ember.js, tabs

Is there any way to determine how many instances of browsers are open and to update the user preference in every open tabs?

I was just checking for a solution to a problem where suppose a user has opened multiple tabs. and he's updating user preferences in one of the tab, then the same preference should be available to all open tabs.

Please see that the word "user preference" is actually application specific.

For example, suppose if a user has opened two tabs, and then in one of the tab he selects the language as English from French, then if he is clicking on any action on different tab, he should be given the language as English only.

Since we can not clear browser cache, there must be some way to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) to store **your user preferences on that browser**. Pick either `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` according to your needs.

There is also an event named [StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent) which is fired in case of a change happened on a storage. So you can handle the cross-tab notifications.

There are some ember addons those wrap the Storage API. Have a look at those addons. Such as [ember-local-storage](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage/).

Last but not least, consider also storing user preferences both at server and at browser.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions - are what you need to do and with or maybe cookies. So if the user selects 'English' 
Then either

a) On the select fire some ajax to the server to set his session language as English

b) Set a cookie as lanaguage = 'English' via javascript or even if the ajax as well.

Then you have to send back the correct language to his on the subsequent tabs when he refreshes those tabs.